# Pay Now Button - How do you change button text?

Tags: civicontribute, paylater

Is there a way to change the "Pay Now" button on contribution pages? The issue is even when the person is selecting to pay by check (Pay Later) the button still says pay now. I want people to click the pay now button be some people find it confusing that you have to hit the pay now button in order for it to send an invoice via email.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this "Pay Now" button you describe. My tests have shown that contribution pages use buttons that read "Confirm Contribution". What version of CiviCRM are you using? Are you able to reproduce this on the [demo site](https://civicrm.org/demo)? Can you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Pay Now" is not the default for CiviCRM I would check to see if Word Replacements has been used to rewrite this. Admin > Customise > Word Replacements ie ../civicrm/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1

If it is not that, then use your browser Inspect option to figure if you have a customised template